# How to use SUM in NHibernate HQL?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying `SUM` using HQL of NHibernate but when execute the query thrown an exception `A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll` and the result isn't return. How could I do this ?

trying.

```
public IList<Conta> findAllContasReceber() {
            ISession _session = getSession();
            IList<Conta> list = _session.CreateQuery("SELECT SUM(c.valorFinal) " + 
                                                     "FROM Conta c " + 
                                                     "WHERE (c.tipoConta = 1) AND (c.status = 0) " + 
                                                     "GROUP BY c.dtVencimento, c.cliente " + 
                                                     "ÖRDER BY c.dtVencimento ASC "
                                                     )                
                .List<Conta>();
            return list;
        }
```

**Entity**

```
[Serializable]
    public class Conta {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }        
        public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
        public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorPagar           { set; get; } //total vendas
        public virtual decimal valorAcrescimo       { set; get; } //total acrescimo
        public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; } //total pagar

        public virtual DateTime dtPagamento         { set; get; }
        public virtual int tipoConta                { set; get; }  //1 receber, 2 pagar
        public virtual PlanoDeConta planoConta      { set; get; }
        public virtual int status                   { set; get; } //0 ativa, 1 fechada, 2 cancelada, 3 aguardando pagamento
        public virtual Venda venda                  { set; get; }


        public Conta() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your select returns a list of numbers (since you are selecting SUM). But you're saying it's a list of Conta. Change your code to `IList<decimal> list = _session...`

Comment: a list of numbers, what does it mean ? I want a `IList<Conta>`.

Comment: If you want a `List<Conta>`, why are you selecting `SUM(c.valorFinal)` instead of `c.*`?

Comment: @Rob because I want to `SUM(c.valorFinal)`. This attribute has values. I'm following this example: `String hql = "SELECT SUM(E.salary), E.firtName FROM Employee E " +
             "GROUP BY E.firstName";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list(); `

Comment: Yes, but the 'answer' is you're getting the total 'valorFinal' for each dtVencimento and cliente. The answer is not rows of Conta, its rows of numbers (because you are *only* selecting the total value). You're essentially asking SQL 'Give me the total of this column'. The answer to that question is not a Conta. It's a number

Comment: understood. Then, how could I do this ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure *what* you are trying to do. If the SQL is correct, change your code to `IList<decimal> list = _session..` as I wrote before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. After looking for a lot of suggestion I found a way to do what I wanted to do.

Here the solution.

```
public IList<Conta> findAllContasReceber() {
            ISession _session = getSession();
            String SQL = "SELECT new Conta(c.cliente, c.historico, c.dtLancamento, c.dtVencimento, SUM(c.valorPagar), SUM(c.valorAcrescimo), SUM(c.valorFinal), c.status) " + 
                         "FROM Conta c WHERE (c.tipoConta = 1) AND (c.status = 0) " + 
                         "GROUP BY c.cliente, c.dtVencimento " + 
                         "ORDER BY c.dtVencimento ";
            IList<Conta> list = _session.CreateQuery(SQL).List<Conta>();
            return list;
        }
```

Then I created a constructor in class Conta to receive parameters

```
[Serializable]
    public class Conta {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }        
        public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
        public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorPagar           { set; get; } //total vendas
        public virtual decimal valorAcrescimo       { set; get; } //total acrescimo
        public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; } //total pagar
        public virtual DateTime dtPagamento         { set; get; }
        public virtual int tipoConta                { set; get; }  //1 receber, 2 pagar
        public virtual PlanoDeConta planoConta      { set; get; }
        public virtual int status                   { set; get; } //0 ativa, 1 fechada, 2 cancelada, 3 aguardando pagamento
        public virtual Venda venda                  { set; get; }


        public Conta() {
        }

        public Conta(Cliente cliente, String historico, DateTime dtLancamento, DateTime dtVencimento, 
                    decimal valorPagar, decimal valorAcrescimo, decimal valorFinal, int status){

                        this.cliente = cliente;
                        this.historico = historico;
                        this.dtLancamento = dtLancamento;
                        this.dtVencimento = dtVencimento;
                        this.valorPagar = valorPagar;
                        this.valorAcrescimo = valorAcrescimo;
                        this.valorFinal = valorFinal;
                        this.status = status;
        }

    }
```

It works 100% finally